# Changing the shortcut keys in outlook 2007

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have been using Gmail for my email for a long time, and I can't go without the j,k email navigation feature.  I recently got a job where I use Outlook 2007, and although they have a shortcut for navigation using CTRL+. and CTRL+, . How do I change the shortcuts from CTRL+ . to just j or just k?

Answer (score 1):

You can't reconfigure shortcuts in Outlook using standard Office tools although you can use AutoHotKey to redefine shortcuts. [This post on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5175724/) has the link to the AutoHotKey script you can use and also there is a short description of shortcuts that work there.

Also, if you want to use this script with Outlook 2010, you should also add **SUPERGRID2** to the *ctrlList* value.